# OpenCL variable assignment fails when using arithmetic expressions with variable

Tags: opencl, gpu, nvidia, hashcat

**Hello, I´m trying to code a kernel using opencl. But Im stuck with a stranger error inside of the kernel function.
The flow is more or less like this:

```
__kernel function1() {
      struct mytype;
      function2(&mytype);
 }

 function2(struct *mytype) {
      uchar *ptr = mytype->value2;
      function3(ptr);
 }

 function3(byte* ptr) {
      uint16 v1 = 10;
      uint16* ptr2 = (uint16*) ptr;
      *ptr2 = v1 >> 8; 
 }


 struct mytype {
       uchar value1[8];
       uchar value2[8];
       uint key[52];
       uint bufleft;
  }
```

The code fails when executing the assignment:

```
*ptr2 = v1 >> 8;
```

But the only message I receive is "clFlush(): CL_UNKNOWN_ERROR"
If I try to assign a value and not an expression, than it works.
I´m using OpenCL 1.2 CUDA in Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be undefined behaviour; if you need to reference the same memory as 2 different types, use a union type. Note that uint16 is a vector of 16 uints, not a ushort (16-bit unsigned integer), and needs to be aligned accordingly. `value2` is only guaranteed to be aligned on a 4-byte boundary (because of the `uint` members of the struct) so this won't be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I am running OpenCL 1.0 on Intel's FPGA SDK for OpenCL (emulator). I had to tweak your code for it to compile, I hopefully didn't change something essential.

```
`struct mytype {
   uchar value1[8];
   uchar value2[8];
   uint key[52];
   uint bufleft;
}; 
void function3(char* ptr) { //I used uchar * ptr too just for kicks, same result
  uint16 v1 = 10;
  uint16* ptr2 = (uint16*) ptr;
  *ptr2 = v1 >> 8; 
}
void function2(struct mytype * a) {
  uchar *ptr = a->value2;
  function3(ptr);
}
__kernel void function1() {
  struct mytype b;
  function2(&b);
}
```

It ran smooth, with no runtime errors, even when I made sure to use -O0. Because of this, I cannot find the exact solution, but after perusing the [OpenCL 1.2 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf), I believe your issue may have to do with Alignment. On page 239 you can find alignment attributes for structs.

I will edit this answer as I dig deeper into the matter, so stay tuned and feel free to edit.